# Redis can't write logs or backup but I need to backup whats currently in memory

Tags: permissions, redis

Someone before me setup a redis instance (version 2.6).

But for some reason, whoever set this, had

- Placed the config file `etc` like this  `/etc/redis.conf`
- The `dir` config has `./` set, like this `dir ./`
- The instance is being run as non-root.

Like this:

```
$ ps aux | grep "redis"`
user  /home/user/redis-stable/src/redis-server /etc/redis.conf
```

- Logging is going to `/dev/null`, because `daemonize yes` && `logfile stdout`

So it is unable to create backups in `/etc/` because it doesn't have permissions (I'm guessing), and I can't even see what is going on because the logs are going to `/dev/null`.

**I want to make a backup so I can turn redis off to fix all these things, without losing any data. Any ideas?**

I've tried:

```
touch /etc/dump.rdb
chown user:users /etc/dump.rdb
```

But it is still not able to write. I'm guessing it might have a temp file it tries to write to before it moves it to `/etc/dump.rdb`

---

After looking at Redis source code, it does seem like there is a temp file: https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/04542cff92147b9b686a2071c4c53574771f4f88/src/rdb.c#L986

```
snprintf(tmpfile,256,"temp-%d.rdb", (int) getpid());
```

---

Also tried

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> config set logfile /home/user/redis.log
(error) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: logfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:

```
config get dir
```

and you would see the directory where redis is saving rdb.

Run:

```
config set dir /home/user/
```

to change the rdb dump directory to /home/user.

then run:

```
redis-cli -p <port> bgsave
```

This would initiate a rdb dump.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Totally worked, I tried `config set logfile` and that didn't work, didn't think to try `config set dir`

Comment: I guess you have to restart redis for logfile and pidfile changes.